# SQL trigger not not allowing to insert value

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

So, I am creating a database using Oracle and this is the problem I ran into. I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE T_SCHEDULE
(
    sched_id number(4) NOT NULL,
    master_id number(10) REFERENCES T_MASTER(master_id) ON DELETE CASCADE NOT NULL,
    client_id number(10) REFERENCES T_CLIENT(client_id) ON DELETE CASCADE NOT NULL,
    box_num number(5) REFERENCES T_BOX(box_num) ON DELETE CASCADE NOT NULL,
    car_num varchar2(10) REFERENCES T_CAR(car_num) ON DELETE CASCADE NOT NULL,
    price number(7) NOT NULL,
    job_start timestamp NOT NULL,
    job_stop timestamp NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(sched_id)
);
```

And this trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER HOURS_A_DAY
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON T_SCHEDULE
    FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE
    v_count number := 0;
    BEGIN
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        INTO v_count
        FROM (SELECT SUM(TO_NUMBER(TRUNC(TO_DATE(job_stop - job_start), 'MI'))) daily
            FROM T_SCHEDULE
            GROUP BY TRUNC(job_start, 'DD'), master_id)
        WHERE daily > 480;
        IF v_count <> 0 THEN
            ROLLBACK;
        END IF;
    END;
```

(The table has references to other tables, but I don't think it's relevant to the problem).
This are the values I am inserting:

```
INSERT INTO T_SCHEDULE VALUES (4001, 1001, 2002, 3002, 'Р232ХВ', 20000, TIMESTAMP '2021-10-02 12:30:00.0', TIMESTAMP '2021-10-02 17:30:00.0');
INSERT INTO T_SCHEDULE VALUES (4002, 1002, 2003, 3003, 'А847КР', 8000, TIMESTAMP '2021-10-02 08:15:00.0', TIMESTAMP '2021-10-02 12:15:00.0');
INSERT INTO T_SCHEDULE VALUES (4003, 1003, 2004, 3005, 'С966ЕС', 5000, TIMESTAMP '2021-10-02 10:45:00.0', TIMESTAMP '2021-10-02 13:45:00.0');
INSERT INTO T_SCHEDULE VALUES (4004, 1004, 2005, 3001, 'Т138УВ', 10000, TIMESTAMP '2021-10-02 10:30:00.0', TIMESTAMP '2021-10-02 15:30:00.0');
INSERT INTO T_SCHEDULE VALUES (4005, 1005, 2006, 3006, 'Р364ВЕ', 15000, TIMESTAMP '2021-10-02 09:00:00.0', TIMESTAMP '2021-10-02 11:00:00.0');
INSERT INTO T_SCHEDULE VALUES (4006, 1001, 2007, 3005, 'О117УУ', 7000, TIMESTAMP '2021-10-03 14:10:00.0', TIMESTAMP '2021-10-02 17:10:00.0');
INSERT INTO T_SCHEDULE VALUES (4007, 1002, 2008, 3002, 'Н439АМ', 30000, TIMESTAMP '2021-10-03 10:40:00.0', TIMESTAMP '2021-10-03 15:40:00.0');
INSERT INTO T_SCHEDULE VALUES (4008, 1003, 2009, 3003, 'О896МТ', 4000, TIMESTAMP '2021-10-02 14:30:00.0', TIMESTAMP '2021-10-02 18:30:00.0');
INSERT INTO T_SCHEDULE VALUES (4009, 1004, 2010, 3004, 'Т694КС', 12000, TIMESTAMP '2021-10-03 09:50:00.0', TIMESTAMP '2021-10-03 17:50:00.0');
INSERT INTO T_SCHEDULE VALUES (4010, 1005, 2001, 3001, 'У601КК', 9000, TIMESTAMP '2021-10-02 16:00:00.0', TIMESTAMP '2021-10-02 20:00:00.0');
```

When I run this, the first row is inserted, however all the others receive ORA-01847 (day of month must be between 1 and last day of month), ORA-06512 (at "SYSTEM.HOURS_A_DAY", line 4) and ORA-04088 (error during execution of trigger 'SYSTEM.HOURS_A_DAY') errors. The main one I think is ORA-01847. All of this to me is weird, since I inserted the same values in the same table, just without the trigger and everything was fine. So I am guessing my trigger affects it. How can I fix it?

Comment: Please list the full error messages. I don’t have them all memorized.

Comment: Also, I’m assuming one of those errors is a mutating table exception. You can’t select from the table the trigger is based on in a 'FOR EACH ROW' timing point.

Comment: @Del It was kinda difficult, since all my log is in russian, but I did my best translating it. Considering your second comment, I didn't know about that, is there any workaround?

Comment: Another problem you are going to have is that a TIMESTAMP-TIMESTAMP is an INTERVAL. ([Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-E405BBC7-DA9A-4DF2-9F22-E60CB9EC0705))

Comment: Subtracting one timestamp from another gives an interval. Trying to convert that to a date deosn't really make sense. What are you trying to do - get the total number of  minutes for all jobs started each day, or at least for start day of the newly inserted (or updated!) job? You'd get the same error outside a trigger; but you also shouldn't roll back within the trigger, and you are likely to get a mutating table error. Maybe explain the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @AlexPoole All the jobs end on the same day they start, that's why I check only job_start. So yeah, I am trying to prevent scheduling more than 8 hours of work a day for each master. That's what the trigger is for. So I need to calculate minutes between two timestamps. You say, I get interval, not a timestamp. OK, fair enough, but as I briefly googled, I didn't find a proper way to truncate an interval, as I did it with timestamp, so what should I do to calculate the minutes?

Comment: That is not what your trigger does. You check if the values already in the table for that day and master_id add up to more than 8 hours and then if it does not you insert the row irrespective of how many hours there are in the new row or what that would do to the total. This is because your trigger is a `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE` trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be checking, for each `master_id` and day, if the total of the time difference between the job start and job end time is more than 8 hours (before you insert the new row).

Which could be simplified to:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER HOURS_A_DAY
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON T_SCHEDULE
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  v_hours number := 0;
BEGIN
  SELECT SUM(CAST(job_stop AS DATE) - CAST(job_start AS DATE)) * 24
  INTO   v_hours
  FROM   T_SCHEDULE
  WHERE  job_start >= TRUNC(:NEW.job_start)
  AND    job_start <  TRUNC(:NEW.job_start) + INTERVAL '1' DAY
  AND    master_id = :NEW.master_id;
      
  IF v_hours > 8 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(
      -20000,
      'Cannot schedule for more than 8 hours in a day.'
    );
  END IF;
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5fbc9d530b3b49b87114449f10843a0e)*

---

## Update - Including the new rows:

Create the types:

```sql
CREATE TYPE hours_detail IS OBJECT(
  master_id NUMBER(10),
  day       DATE,
  hours     NUMBER
);

CREATE TYPE hours_tbl IS TABLE OF hours_detail;
```

Then the compound trigger:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER hours_a_day
FOR INSERT OR UPDATE ON t_schedule
COMPOUND TRIGGER
  hours        hours_tbl;
  v_overbooked PLS_INTEGER;
BEFORE STATEMENT
  IS
  BEGIN
    SELECT hours_detail(
             master_id,
             TRUNC(job_start),
             SUM(CAST(job_stop AS DATE) - CAST(job_start AS DATE)) * 24
           )
    BULK COLLECT INTO hours
    FROM   T_SCHEDULE
    GROUP BY master_id, TRUNC(job_start);
  END BEFORE STATEMENT;
BEFORE EACH ROW
  IS
  BEGIN
    hours.EXTEND();
    hours(hours.COUNT) := hours_detail(
      :NEW.master_id,
      TRUNC(:NEW.job_start),
      (CAST(:NEW.job_stop AS DATE) - CAST(:NEW.job_start AS DATE)) * 24
      - COALESCE(
          (CAST(:OLD.job_stop AS DATE) - CAST(:OLD.job_start AS DATE)) * 24,
          0
        )
    );
  END BEFORE EACH ROW;
AFTER STATEMENT
  IS
  BEGIN
    SELECT 1
    INTO   v_overbooked
    FROM   TABLE(hours)
    GROUP BY master_id, day
    HAVING SUM(hours) > 8
    FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;

    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(
      -20000,
      'Cannot schedule for more than 8 hours in a day.'
    );
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      NULL;
  END AFTER STATEMENT;
END;
/
```

This will raise errors when multiple rows are inserted at the same time that individually do not total more than 8 hours but together go over that limit.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3af64a842ee21ce1c4edcd47acabb913)*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I may not understand correctly what you did here, but the value of v_hours seem to be selected directly from T_SCHEDULE, which as you pointed out in the comment, does not yet contain the new row. Am I wrong in thinking so?

Comment: @ВладиславКрутенко I am assuming that the behaviour of the code in the question is "as intended" and this answer is a "fixed" version of that exactly code; I do not aim to second guess what is intended and whether or not the behaviour of the code is correct or not (especially when there is no description in the question of what the code is intended to do and that only comes out later in comments). If you want one that takes the new row(s) into account then you are going to have a much more complicated solution (which I imagine would probably end up as a compound trigger).

Comment: I am not saying you had to do it, I am just verifying if I understand it correctly.

Comment: @ВладиславКрутенко Updated with a compound trigger that does what you intend.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in `SUM(TO_NUMBER(TRUNC(TO_DATE(job_stop - job_start), 'MI')))`. `job_stop - job_start`, a calculation involving two TIMESTAMPs, returns a INTERVAL rather than a DATE or a NUMBER. As such, you need to extract the days, hours, minutes, and seconds from the resulting interval, adjusting each to a value in seconds.

You've also got a couple other potential issues:

1. You're selecting from T_SCHEDULE in a trigger defined on T_SCHEDULE. This is likely to cause an ORA-04091 "Table T_SCHEDULE is mutating; trigger cannot see it" error. The solution is to define this as a statement trigger rather than a row trigger, by simply removing the `FOR EACH ROW` line. In this case this should work, but in many cases it's not a viable solution and other solutions will have to be tried.
2. You're trying to perform a ROLLBACK in a trigger. This is not allowed - raise an exception instead.

Putting this all together we get:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER HOURS_A_DAY
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON T_SCHEDULE
DECLARE
  v_count number := 0;
BEGIN
  WITH cteInterval
    AS (SELECT JOB_START,
               MASTER_ID,
               job_stop - job_start AS JOB_INTERVAL
          FROM T_SCHEDULE)
  SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO v_count
    FROM (SELECT SUM((EXTRACT(DAY    FROM JOB_INTERVAL) * 24 * 60 * 60) +
                     (EXTRACT(HOUR   FROM JOB_INTERVAL) * 60 * 60)      +
                     (EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM JOB_INTERVAL) * 60)           +
                     (EXTRACT(SECOND FROM JOB_INTERVAL))) / 60 AS daily
            FROM cteInterval
            GROUP BY TRUNC(job_start, 'DD'),
                     master_id)
    WHERE daily > 480;

  IF v_count <> 0 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Difference greater than 8 hours found');
  END IF;
END HOURS_A_DAY;
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a4fdeda1fb64751866456738dd3cdd28)